# How do I go about framing a half wall into a full wall?

Tags: walls, framing, studs, carpentry

My house has an second floor open loft area with a half wall that overlooks the foyer down below. I would like to enclose the half wall, add a closet and door to create a fourth bedroom. How do I go about framing the half wall into a full wall? I included the floor plan, which shows the option for the fourth bedroom. The half wall is where the optional handrail is listed in the Loft.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you were to just frame up the current opening above the half wall, you're going to run in to problems with the wall flexing, possibly cracking the drywall.

Therefore, at a minimum, I would put at least a doubled-up stud at the end of the half-wall that runs from the floor to the ceiling. (But first remove drywall and trim from the end and top of the half-wall.)  The floor-to-ceiling double stud will resist the flexing. Then you just fill in the opening with a header, footer and studs; hang some drywall; and patch and paint.

However, to do it "right" you would remove the half-wall and just frame in a new wall using traditional building methods.

Personally, I would choose the right way. It's probably not much difference in effort and price and you end up with a more standard finished product.

Comment: Trickiest part could be  finding someplace to stand while hanging the drywall on the outer side of the new wall  :)

Comment: I wouldnt even consider the first option. Just do it the right way.

Comment: Add some insulation in the wall, if sound reduction is desired.  Even a little bit of fiberglass does something, dense pack cellulose is better.